# Why am i getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)?

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to write a program that, when given a certain price, will break it into 20s, 10s, 5s and 1s.

However, I am getting the following error: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

The error shows up on the line: `*tens=diff` in the function.
I do not understand what is wrong!

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void pay_month(int , int *, int *, int *, int *);

int main(){

int dollars, *twenties=0, *tens=0, *fives=0, *ones=0;

printf("enter amount to pay: ");
scanf("%d",&dollars);

pay_month(dollars, twenties, tens, fives, ones);


return 0;
}
void pay_month(int dollars, int *twenties, int *tens, int *fives, int 
*ones){

int diff=0;
int odolls;

odolls=dollars;


while(dollars%20!=0){
    dollars=dollars-1;
    diff++;
}

*tens=diff;

*twenties=dollars/20;

diff=0;

while(*tens%10!=0){
    *tens=*tens-1;
    diff++;
}

*tens=*tens/10;

*fives=diff;

diff=0;

while(*fives%5!=0){
    *fives=*fives-1;
    diff++;
}

*ones=diff;


diff=0;

while(*ones%1!=0){
    *ones=*ones-1;
    diff++;
}

printf("in %d there is %d twentis %d tens %d fives and %d ones\n",odolls, *twenties, *tens, *fives, *ones); 

}
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{', Unindent before every closing brace '}',  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do..,while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions via 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent). 4) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  5) use appropriate horizontal spacing inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to scatter data away for where that data is being set/used.  In the current scenario.  the data is being declared in `main()` and being set/used in `pay_month()`

Comment: The logic in the function: `pay_month()` does not perform the desired function.  Suggest using a debugger and stepping through that function so you know what is actually happening

Answer (score 3):

You are dereferencing a NULL pointer.  That is, you are asking the computer to write into memory location `0`.  You are not allowed to do that.

I think what you've done is used pointers without quite understanding how to obtain them.  Possibly just to stop the compiler from throwing errors.

This simple change should solve the problem:

```
int dollars, twenties=0, tens=0, fives=0, ones=0;

printf("enter amount to pay: ");
scanf("%d",&dollars);

pay_month(dollars, &twenties, &tens, &fives, &ones);
```

Notice that none of the values in the calling function are pointers anymore.  They're just integers.  You prefix with `&` when passing them to `pay_month`.  That's the *reference* operator, which obtains a pointer to where the value is stored.

Now, when you dereference the `tens` pointer inside `pay_month`, you're actually accessing the same part of memory where the value `tens` is stored on the stack in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

a classic case of pointers and variables

essentially when you are declaring pointer as

```
int *twenties=0, *tens=0, *fives=0, *ones=0;
```

you are essentially making these pointers to point to `NULL` memory which means no memory is allocated to those.

one way to solve this is by declaring these as variables and passing the address of these variables

```
int dollars, twenties=0, tens=0, fives=0, ones=0;
```

and

```
pay_month(dollars, &twenties, &tens, &fives, &ones);
```